# Generate tuples to iterate over in one for loop

Tags: python, iterator, tuples

I'd like to reduce three for loops into one by generating all the iterators in one go. Basically I have a dictionary that uses tuples as its keys. I know I can do

```
for aa in range(limitA):
    for bb in range(limitB):
        for cc in range(limitC):
            do_stuff(my_dict[(aa,bb,cc)])
```

But is there a way that requires less lines of code? Something like

```
for aa,bb,cc in range(limitA), range(limitB), range(limitC):
    do_stuff(my_dict[(aa,bb,cc)])
```

This returns the error "`ValueError: need more than 2 values to unpack`"

If this cannot be done generally, does the special case of `limitA == limitB == limitC` have a solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`itertools.product()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
from itertools import product

for aa, bb, cc in product(range(limitA), range(limitB), range(limitC)):
```

Where `limitA == limitB == limitC` this can be simplified to:

```
for aa, bb, cc in product(range(limitA), repeat=3):
```

Comment: Wow, that was fast. I'll try that

Comment: Straight to the point, an answer that not only works, but gives me lots of ideas about how I can nest my other for loops, and all done within 30 seconds of posting the question. Thanks mate! (I can't accept your answer yet because it's not yet 2 mins :)